# Convert xml ComboBox to javascript view

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I am new to OpenUI5, i have a combobox created using XML view so now i need to create the same combobox but in a JavaScript View. My version is 1.58.2:

My xml combobox code is as follows and it works:

```
 <ComboBox 
     id="departmentsDropDown"
     selectionChange="handleSelectionChange"
     items="{ path: 'departments>/' }"
     placeholder="{i18n>departmentSelect}" >     
     <core:Item key="{departments>name}" text="{departments>org_unit}" />  
</ComboBox>
```

My JavaScript view code is as follows and it gives me an error:

```
var comboBox = new sap.m.ComboBox(this.createId("departmentsComboBox"),{            
            items : "{ path: 'departments>/' }",
            selectionChange : oController.handleSelectionChange
});
```

Error:

```
Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.ComboBox#__jsview1--departmentsComboBox ! -
```

Comment: is there a reason for you to use JSviews? XML ones are standard duo to good reason....https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/01/why-do-we-use-xml-views-rather-js-views-in-sapui5/

Comment: @Erch yes, I am creating a Tree dynamically (custom tree) based on the data available. Therefore my tree nodes cardinality would be 0...n. XML tree will not be able to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the javascript side, you need to provide information on what to do with the actual line inside the combobox, IE the template. In the XML it's provided; you're using `core:Item` for this. It is missing on the javascript side. Here's an example of how to add it:

```
new sap.m.ComboBox({
    selectedKey: '{model>/key}',
    showSecondaryValues: true,
    items: {
      path: '/Model',
      template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
        key: '{Key}',
        text: '{Key}',
        additionalText: '{Description}'
      })
    },
    change: _ => {
       //change logic
    }
  })
```

It's not exactly the same but you it shows how to add a template. You'll find you'll need the same kind of logic for any control with an aggregation like lists or tables. For more complex controls, you could use a fragment too.